# QEMU "tgc fatal error" on ARM laptop?

Tags: arm, qemu

I'm trying to emulate an x86 Debian machine on an ARM laptop.
I am following the tutorial here:
https://wiki.debian.org/QEMU#Operation

The issue is, when I run this command:

```
    $ qemu-system-i386 -hda debian.img -cdrom debian-testing-i386-businesscard.iso -boot d -m 256
```

it throws this error:

> /build/buildd/qemu-kvm-1.0+noroms/tcg/arm/tcg-target.c:859: tcg fatal error
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

I have not managed to find any solutions.

Comment: Which qmeu version? 1.0 sounds accient

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very old QEMU and the error report indicates an internal bug in the TCG translator. Try with a more recent build of QEMU and perhaps raise a bug if the problem is still present.